# Angular2 Animation onDone callback

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Anyone know how to catch `onDone` callback for new animation system in angular2? There is an animation - and I want to do some stuff `onDone`... I saw in sources of angular2 this method at `AnimationPlayer` interface, but nothing has been exposed to users...

With best regards! Very appreciate yours answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the forthcoming RC6 release this will be supported via `(@animation.done)`: https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/45e8e73670b96387fc109921fad299742d3f7cbf

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
import {AnimationPlayer} from '@angular/core';
```

```
constructor(animationPlayer:AnimationPlayer) {
  animationPlayer.onDone(() => {
    console.log('animation done');
  });
}
```

Comment: yep, it doesn't work, AnimationPlayer is just Interface(

Comment: `AnimationPlayer` is the common base class for all animation players. So what does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I would create a feature request in the Angular2 GitHub repo.

Comment: Injecting works if there is some instance in provide system, and for `AnimationPlayer` there isn't. In fact in `@angular/core` namespace none realization of `AnimationPlayer` is presented so far.

Comment: I see. As mentioned, I'd create a feature request. The requirement sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Thank for your responsiveness.  I guess this feature is somewhere on the roadmap because I definitely saw at ng-conf2016 examples of some raw API... Just was a little surprised by not to find it there. I thought maybe was unobservant.