# Angular 2 RC2 onanimationend

Tags: angular

How could I subscribe to animationend event with this given component?
I cannot add more details.

```
@Component({
host: {
    '[class.like-popover]' : 'true'
},
selector: 'like-tooltip',
template: `<div @flyInOut="'in'">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner">{{text}}</div>
</div>`,
styleUrls: ['like-tooltip.component.css'],
animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
        state('in', style({opacity: 1})),
        transition('* => *', [
            animate('2s linear', keyframes([
                style({opacity: 1, offset: 0}),
                style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(0, -100%, 0)', offset: 1}),
            ]))
        ])
    ])
]})
export class LikeToolTipComponent {
constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef) {
}
```

Sorry for the duplicate: [Angular2 Animation onDone callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108993/angular2-animation-ondone-callback)

Comment: WHat do you mean by subscribe? doesn't it work?

Comment: I mean detecting animation end somehow.  I tried this way:
```_elementRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', () => console.log("anim end"));``` or only with one or other event name. The best would be to make an observable from the event something like this: ``` Observable.fromEvent(_elementRef.nativeElement, 'animationend').take(1).subscribe(e => {
          console.log("anim end");
        });```

Answer (score 0):

RC.6 introduced animation callbacks like:

```
(@flyInOut.start)="animationStarted($event)"
(@flyInOut.done)="animationDone($event)"#
```

```
animationStarted(event: AnimationTransitionEvent) {
  console.warn('Animation started: ', event);
}

animationDone(event: AnimationTransitionEvent) {
  console.warn('Animation done: ', event);
}
```

Comment: That's nice but what can I do if I'm not allowed to upgrade?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.